# why appears this warnings

Tags: solidity, remix, ide

browser/ballot.sol:3:28: Warning: Functions in interfaces should be declared external.

```
interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) public; }
                           ^-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

browser/ballot.sol:185:17: Warning: Using contract member "balance" inherited from the address type is deprecated. Convert the contract to "address" type to access the member, for example use "address(contract).balance" instead.

```
require(this.balance >= amount * sellPrice);      // checks if the contract has enough ether to buy
        ^----------^
```

Comment: You changed the entire question after a perfectly correct answer to it. Prefer asking a new question when your previous one gets answered.

Comment: Lol, changed again. Why do people not understand the meaning of a downvote.

Comment: sorry, i actually don't know how to use properlty this platform, i´m new, but from now i'll publicate a new cuestion if i have one

Answer (score 0):

The problems:

- Constructor declared incorrectly. It does not require contract name.
- `C` should be small cases in `constructor`.

Constructor can be declared by using the keyword `constructor` and nothing else is required. The correct way is as follows:

```
constructor(uint256 initialSupply , string tokenName , string tokenSymbol) public {
}
```

**Update:**

Resolving new errors:

- `assign` is not a valid keyword. Remove assign and errors will be gone.

Comment: thank you i fixed, but now appears another errors

Comment: do you know how to fix the new ones?

Comment: @Roy I have updated my answer

Comment: thank you, but now a got a warning

Comment: @Roy read the warning. They answer your questions. And don't worry about them, they are just warnings.

Comment: ok thank you, doy ou know what does this mean? Static Analysis raised 6 warning(s) that requires your attention.